# Reservoir Concept with Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

In some cases, we do not want to treat certain data as soon as they arrive, but after some time.

My question's : is there a way to implement the concept of a reservoir with Spark Streaming ?!

I mean how to temporarily store some DStream data (based on a condition) in a structure (called reservoir) and process them later !!

Comment: You probably know this, but *reservoir* in a context of data streams usually refer to sampling => increasingly imprecise storage.

Answer (score 0):

you can use collect function to collect a dataset : 
example : 
collect a dataset of tweet :

```
val tweetStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, Utils.getAuth)
  .map(gson.toJson(_))

tweetStream.foreachRDD((rdd, time) => {
  val count = rdd.count()
  if (count > 0) {
    val outputRDD = rdd.repartition(partitionsEachInterval)
    outputRDD.saveAsTextFile(
      outputDirectory + "/tweets_" + time.milliseconds.toString)
    numTweetsCollected += count
    if (numTweetsCollected > numTweetsToCollect) {
      System.exit(0)
    }
  }
})
```